# Is there a way to use quicklisp with GCL?

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, gnu-common-lisp

Installation/`(load "/home/inaimathi/quicklisp/setup.lisp")` both fail. This [still-open task](http://savannah.gnu.org/support/?107611#discussion) from 2011 tells me it's probably not getting fixed.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Xach - Reasons. (I'm trying to do some Lisping on ARM, and the other available CLs either can't seem to run `hunchentoot`, have odd restrictions on the use of streams, or aren't available from the ARM Debian repos). I take it that this is basically a "you can't"?

Comment: I don't know if you can, but if you want to do Lisping on ARM, I think Clozure CL is far and away the better bet, as it is actively maintained and is the second most popular Common Lisp implementation, so likely to have much better software support than GCL.

Comment: Just to add perspective, the last version of GCL seems to be from 2005, 7 years ago.

Comment: Clozure was going to be the thing I tried if this didn't pan out. I guess that's that then. Did one of you guys want to put that up as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Clozure CL](http://ccl.clozure.com/) and [SBCl](http://www.sbcl.org/) both can run hunchentoot web server on ARM.

Comment: SBCL does not yet implement threading on ARM, so CCL is probably a better bet.